# Force Close When Starting New Activity

Tags: java, android

So when I click the "Do Something Useless Button" Android Forces A Close on my App. Here is my code:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button doUseless;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        doUseless = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bUselessTask);
        doUseless.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent openUseless = new Intent("com.apps.epicad.USELESS");
                startActivity(openUseless);

        }
            });
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Andrew's App Has Started!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.apps.epicad.andrewapp"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:icon="@drawable/eva">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.apps.epicad.ANDREWAPP" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity android:name=".UselessActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.apps.epicad.USELESS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

UselessActivity.java:

```
public class UselessActivity extends Activity {

    Button doUseless;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        doUseless = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bDoUseless);
        doUseless.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ProgressDialog dia = new ProgressDialog(UselessActivity.this);
                dia.show(getApplication(), "Doing Something", "Being Epic", true, true);

            }
        });
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Andrew's App Has Showed Do Something Useless Screen!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();


    }

}
```

LogCat:

```
08-18 19:08:06.550: DEBUG/ConnectivityService(1310): getMobileDataEnabled returning true
08-18 19:08:07.731: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2516): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
08-18 19:08:07.731: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2516): CheckJNI is OFF
08-18 19:08:07.731: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2516): creating instr width table
08-18 19:08:07.891: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2516): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
08-18 19:08:07.911: WARN/PackageManager(1310): grantUriPermission URI=file:///data/local/tmp/AndrewApp.apk
08-18 19:08:07.942: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2364): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4K, 50% free 2703K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 23ms
08-18 19:08:07.962: DEBUG/PackageParser(1310): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl-1797381420.tmp
08-18 19:08:07.962: WARN/ActivityManager(1310): No content provider found for: 
08-18 19:08:08.022: INFO/PackageManager(1310): Removing non-system package:com.apps.epicad.andrewapp
08-18 19:08:08.022: INFO/ActivityManager(1310): Force stopping package com.apps.epicad.andrewapp uid=10161
08-18 19:08:08.182: DEBUG/lights(1310): set_light_buttons_func: on=5329233 brightness=81
08-18 19:08:08.182: DEBUG/lights(1310): set_light_buttons_func: on=16777215 brightness=255
08-18 19:08:08.272: DEBUG/DEBUG(2737): updateCellLayoutCache(3.5555556, 3.5607476)
08-18 19:08:08.792: DEBUG/PackageManager(1310): Scanning package com.apps.epicad.andrewapp
08-18 19:08:08.792: DEBUG/installd(1220): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.apps.epicad.andrewapp-2.apk' ---
08-18 19:08:08.792: INFO/PackageManager(1310): Package com.apps.epicad.andrewapp codePath changed from /data/app/com.apps.epicad.andrewapp-1.apk to /data/app/com.apps.epicad.andrewapp-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
08-18 19:08:08.792: INFO/PackageManager(1310): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/com.apps.epicad.andrewapp-2.apk
08-18 19:08:08.812: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2526): creating instr width table
08-18 19:08:08.832: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2526): DexOpt: load 4ms, verify+opt 13ms
08-18 19:08:08.832: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(1531): onSignalStrengthsChanged
08-18 19:08:08.842: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(1531): ATT SignalStrength:  asu=7 signalDbm=100 ecno=18
08-18 19:08:08.852: DEBUG/installd(1220): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.apps.epicad.andrewapp-2.apk' (success) ---
08-18 19:08:08.852: INFO/ActivityManager(1310): Force stopping package com.apps.epicad.andrewapp uid=10161
08-18 19:08:08.852: WARN/PackageManager(1310): Code path for pkg : com.apps.epicad.andrewapp changing from /data/app/com.apps.epicad.andrewapp-1.apk to /data/app/com.apps.epicad.andrewapp-2.apk
08-18 19:08:08.862: DEBUG/PackageManager(1310):   Activities: com.apps.epicad.andrewapp.SplashActivity com.apps.epicad.andrewapp.MainActivity
08-18 19:08:08.862: WARN/PackageManager(1310): Resource path for pkg : com.apps.epicad.andrewapp changing from /data/app/com.apps.epicad.andrewapp-1.apk to /data/app/com.apps.epicad.andrewapp-2.apk
08-18 19:08:09.063: INFO/installd(1220): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.apps.epicad.andrewapp-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.apps.epicad.andrewapp-2.apk@classes.dex
08-18 19:08:09.063: DEBUG/PackageManager(1310): New package installed in /data/app/com.apps.epicad.andrewapp-2.apk
08-18 19:08:09.183: INFO/ActivityManager(1310): Force stopping package com.apps.epicad.andrewapp uid=10161
08-18 19:08:09.303: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1310): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1367K, 45% free 9985K/17863K, external 4504K/5618K, paused 114ms
08-18 19:08:09.353: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1547): GC_EXPLICIT freed 467K, 49% free 4679K/9031K, external 1301K/1813K, paused 154ms
08-18 19:08:09.393: DEBUG/PhoneApp(1544): -- PackageChangeBroadcastReceiver  action = android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
08-18 19:08:09.723: DEBUG/szipinf(1310): Initializing inflate state
08-18 19:08:09.873: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1310): GC_EXPLICIT freed 258K, 44% free 10040K/17863K, external 4504K/5618K, paused 111ms
08-18 19:08:09.893: WARN/ResourceType(26733): getEntry failing because entryIndex 187 is beyond type entryCount 123
08-18 19:08:09.893: WARN/ResourceType(26733): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0200bb (t=1 e=187) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
08-18 19:08:09.913: WARN/ResourceType(26733): getEntry failing because entryIndex 187 is beyond type entryCount 123
08-18 19:08:09.913: WARN/ResourceType(26733): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0200bb (t=1 e=187) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
08-18 19:08:09.923: WARN/ResourceType(26733): getEntry failing because entryIndex 187 is beyond type entryCount 123
08-18 19:08:09.923: WARN/ResourceType(26733): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0200bb (t=1 e=187) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
08-18 19:08:09.973: DEBUG/dalvikvm(26733): GC_CONCURRENT freed 453K, 49% free 3148K/6151K, external 20K/532K, paused 2ms+8ms
08-18 19:08:09.994: WARN/ResourceType(26733): getEntry failing because entryIndex 187 is beyond type entryCount 123
08-18 19:08:09.994: WARN/ResourceType(26733): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0200bb (t=1 e=187) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
08-18 19:08:10.004: WARN/ResourceType(26733): getEntry failing because entryIndex 187 is beyond type entryCount 123
08-18 19:08:10.004: WARN/ResourceType(26733): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0200bb (t=1 e=187) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
08-18 19:08:10.014: WARN/ResourceType(26733): getEntry failing because entryIndex 187 is beyond type entryCount 123
08-18 19:08:10.014: WARN/ResourceType(26733): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0200bb (t=1 e=187) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
08-18 19:08:10.024: WARN/ResourceType(26733): getEntry failing because entryIndex 187 is beyond type entryCount 123
08-18 19:08:10.024: WARN/ResourceType(26733): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0200bb (t=1 e=187) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
08-18 19:08:10.024: WARN/ResourceType(26733): getEntry failing because entryIndex 187 is beyond type entryCount 123
08-18 19:08:10.024: WARN/ResourceType(26733): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0200bb (t=1 e=187) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
08-18 19:08:10.074: DEBUG/PhoneApp(1544): -- PackageChangeBroadcastReceiver  action = android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
08-18 19:08:10.104: INFO/installd(1220): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.apps.epicad.andrewapp-1.apk@classes.dex
08-18 19:08:10.114: DEBUG/HomeLoaders(2737): get install or remove message so do change adapter
08-18 19:08:10.114: DEBUG/HomeLoaders(2737): get install or remove message so do change adapter
08-18 19:08:10.174: DEBUG/ConnectivityService(1310): getMobileDataEnabled returning true
08-18 19:08:10.504: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2737): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 857K, 44% free 5705K/10055K, external 23735K/23754K, paused 58ms
08-18 19:08:10.574: DEBUG/DEBUG(2737): updateCellLayoutCache(3.5555556, 3.5607476)
08-18 19:08:10.604: DEBUG/DEBUG(2737): updateCellLayoutCache(3.5555556, 3.5607476)
08-18 19:08:10.664: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(1310): New lightsensor value:10, lcdValue:81
08-18 19:08:10.664: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(1310): lightSensorChangedLocked, buttonValue >= 0, mPowerState = 3
08-18 19:08:10.674: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2516): Shutting down VM
08-18 19:08:10.674: DEBUG/VoiceDialerReceiver(2378): onReceive Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.apps.epicad.andrewapp flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.voicedialer/.VoiceDialerReceiver (has extras) }
08-18 19:08:10.674: VERBOSE/RecognizerEngine(2378): deleteCachedGrammarFiles /data/data/com.android.voicedialer/files/openentries.txt
08-18 19:08:10.704: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2516): GC_CONCURRENT freed 103K, 69% free 323K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+1ms
08-18 19:08:10.704: INFO/AndroidRuntime(2516): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
08-18 19:08:10.704: DEBUG/vicky(1059): vicky received: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
08-18 19:08:10.704: DEBUG/jdwp(2516): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
08-18 19:08:10.704: DEBUG/DEBUG(2737): updateCellLayoutCache(3.5555556, 3.5607476)
08-18 19:08:10.714: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2516): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-18 19:08:10.844: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2737): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 59K, 44% free 5666K/10055K, external 25606K/25635K, paused 51ms
08-18 19:08:10.894: DEBUG/DEBUG(2737): updateCellLayoutCache(3.5555556, 3.5607476)
08-18 19:08:10.904: DEBUG/DEBUG(2737): updateCellLayoutCache(3.5555556, 3.5607476)
08-18 19:08:10.904: INFO/RegisterService(2387): android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED package:com.apps.epicad.andrewapp
08-18 19:08:10.924: DEBUG/DEBUG(2737): updateCellLayoutCache(3.5555556, 3.5607476)
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837552
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837527
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837559
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837508
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837627
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837513
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837504
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837518
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837648
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130838372
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130838095
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130838178
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837562
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837562
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837691
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837608
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837542
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130903040
08-18 19:08:10.994: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130903040
08-18 19:08:11.465: DEBUG/szipinf(1547): Initializing inflate state
08-18 19:08:11.525: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837552
08-18 19:08:11.525: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837527
08-18 19:08:11.535: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837559
08-18 19:08:11.535: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837508
08-18 19:08:11.535: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837627
08-18 19:08:11.535: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837513
08-18 19:08:11.535: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837504
08-18 19:08:11.535: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837518
08-18 19:08:11.535: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837648
08-18 19:08:11.535: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130838372
08-18 19:08:11.535: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130838095
08-18 19:08:11.545: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130838178
08-18 19:08:11.545: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837562
08-18 19:08:11.545: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837562
08-18 19:08:11.545: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837691
08-18 19:08:11.545: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837608
08-18 19:08:11.545: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130837542
08-18 19:08:11.545: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130903040
08-18 19:08:11.545: WARN/Addapter(2737): info.icon:2130903040
08-18 19:08:11.595: INFO/RosieUtility(921): disable self killer: mEnabled=1
08-18 19:08:11.605: INFO/RosieUtility(921): enable self killer: mEnabled=0
08-18 19:08:11.615: DEBUG/HtcWidgetScanner(921): action - android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
08-18 19:08:11.615: INFO/RosieUtility(921): disable self killer: mEnabled=1
08-18 19:08:11.615: DEBUG/HtcWidgetScanner(921): packageUid - 10161
08-18 19:08:11.625: INFO/RosieUtility(921): enable self killer: mEnabled=0
08-18 19:08:11.645: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(1531): onSignalStrengthsChanged
08-18 19:08:11.645: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(1531): ATT SignalStrength:  asu=5 signalDbm=103 ecno=20
08-18 19:08:11.665: DEBUG/VoiceDialerReceiver(2378): onReceive Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.apps.epicad.andrewapp flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.voicedialer/.VoiceDialerReceiver (has extras) }
08-18 19:08:11.665: VERBOSE/RecognizerEngine(2378): deleteCachedGrammarFiles /data/data/com.android.voicedialer/files/openentries.txt
08-18 19:08:11.695: DEBUG/vicky(1059): vicky received: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
08-18 19:08:11.715: INFO/RegisterService(2387): android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED package:com.apps.epicad.andrewapp
08-18 19:08:11.725: INFO/RosieUtility(921): disable self killer: mEnabled=1
08-18 19:08:11.725: INFO/RosieUtility(921): enable self killer: mEnabled=0
08-18 19:08:11.745: DEBUG/HtcWidgetScanner(921): action - android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
08-18 19:08:11.745: INFO/RosieUtility(921): disable self killer: mEnabled=1
08-18 19:08:11.745: DEBUG/HtcWidgetScanner(921): packageUid - 10161
08-18 19:08:11.745: INFO/RosieUtility(921): enable self killer: mEnabled=0
08-18 19:08:11.805: INFO/RegisterService(2387): android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED package:com.apps.epicad.andrewapp
08-18 19:08:11.935: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2540): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
08-18 19:08:11.935: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2540): CheckJNI is OFF
08-18 19:08:11.935: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2540): creating instr width table
08-18 19:08:12.086: DEBUG/PhoneApp(1544): EVENT_QUERY_MO_PACKAGES
08-18 19:08:12.086: DEBUG/PhoneApp(1544): -- N1 =0
08-18 19:08:12.096: DEBUG/PhoneApp(1544): -- N2 =0
08-18 19:08:12.106: DEBUG/PhoneApp(1544): -- N3 =0
08-18 19:08:12.126: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2540): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
08-18 19:08:12.126: INFO/ActivityManager(1310): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.apps.epicad.andrewapp/.SplashActivity } from pid 2540
08-18 19:08:12.156: VERBOSE/HtcAppUsageStats(1310): (launch app, package): (AndrewApp, com.apps.epicad.andrewapp)
08-18 19:08:12.156: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2540): Shutting down VM
08-18 19:08:12.166: INFO/[POST_RESELECT](2737): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@4012ceb0,-1,0,-1,0)
08-18 19:08:12.166: INFO/[POST_RESELECT](2737): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@40140890,-1,0,-1,0)
08-18 19:08:12.166: DEBUG/Background traffic light(2737): traffic light: GREEN, mBackgroundTrafficLight = true
08-18 19:08:12.176: INFO/ActivityManager(1310): Start proc com.apps.epicad.andrewapp for activity com.apps.epicad.andrewapp/.SplashActivity: pid=2548 uid=10161 gids={}
08-18 19:08:12.206: DEBUG/Sensors(1310): Enable akm: en = 1
08-18 19:08:12.206: DEBUG/SensorService(1310): noteStartSensor: uid = 0x3e8, handle = 0x0
08-18 19:08:12.226: INFO/AndroidRuntime(2540): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
08-18 19:08:12.226: DEBUG/AK8975(1223): Compass Start
08-18 19:08:12.266: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(1310): layer=0x65b980 is not in the purgatory list
08-18 19:08:12.366: WARN/InputManagerService(1310): [unbindCurrentClientLocked] Disable input method client.
08-18 19:08:12.366: WARN/InputManagerService(1310): [startInputLocked] Enable input method client.
08-18 19:08:12.386: WARN/dalvikvm(2737): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
08-18 19:08:12.396: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2540): GC_CONCURRENT freed 104K, 66% free 353K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 5ms+1ms
08-18 19:08:12.396: DEBUG/jdwp(2540): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
08-18 19:08:12.396: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2540): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-18 19:08:12.546: INFO/ActivityManager(1310): Displayed com.apps.epicad.andrewapp/.SplashActivity: +368ms
08-18 19:08:12.696: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(1310): layer=0x90c838 is not in the purgatory list
08-18 19:08:13.177: DEBUG/ConnectivityService(1310): getMobileDataEnabled returning true
08-18 19:08:16.190: DEBUG/ConnectivityService(1310): getMobileDataEnabled returning true
08-18 19:08:17.311: INFO/ActivityManager(1310): Starting activity: Intent { act=com.apps.epicad.ANDREWAPP cmp=com.apps.epicad.andrewapp/.MainActivity } from pid 2548
08-18 19:08:17.501: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(1531): onSignalStrengthsChanged
08-18 19:08:17.501: DEBUG/StatusBarPolicy(1531): ATT SignalStrength:  asu=3 signalDbm=107 ecno=21
08-18 19:08:17.581: INFO/ActivityManager(1310): Displayed com.apps.epicad.andrewapp/.MainActivity: +263ms
08-18 19:08:17.591: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(1310): layer=0x691b08 is not in the purgatory list
08-18 19:08:19.202: DEBUG/ConnectivityService(1310): getMobileDataEnabled returning true
08-18 19:08:19.503: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2548): Shutting down VM
08-18 19:08:19.503: WARN/dalvikvm(2548): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
08-18 19:08:19.503: INFO/ActivityManager(1310): Starting activity: Intent { act=com.apps.epicad.USELESS } from pid 2548
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.apps.epicad.USELESS }
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1569)
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1539)
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2901)
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3007)
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548):     at com.apps.epicad.andrewapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:25)
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9277)
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-18 19:08:19.513: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2548):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-18 19:08:19.513: WARN/ActivityManager(1310):   Force finishing activity com.apps.epicad.andrewapp/.MainActivity
08-18 19:08:19.833: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(1310): layer=0x90c838 is not in the purgatory list
08-18 19:08:20.013: WARN/ActivityManager(1310): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{406b5360 com.apps.epicad.andrewapp/.MainActivity}
08-18 19:08:21.445: INFO/Process(2548): Sending signal. PID: 2548 SIG: 9
08-18 19:08:21.495: ERROR/InputDispatcher(1310): channel '406b0f48 com.apps.epicad.andrewapp/com.apps.epicad.andrewapp.SplashActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
08-18 19:08:21.495: ERROR/InputDispatcher(1310): channel '406b0f48 com.apps.epicad.andrewapp/com.apps.epicad.andrewapp.SplashActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-18 19:08:21.495: INFO/ActivityManager(1310): Process com.apps.epicad.andrewapp (pid 2548) has died.
08-18 19:08:21.505: INFO/WindowManager(1310): WINDOW DIED Window{406b0f48 com.apps.epicad.andrewapp/com.apps.epicad.andrewapp.SplashActivity paused=false}
08-18 19:08:21.515: ERROR/InputDispatcher(1310): channel '4070fd50 com.apps.epicad.andrewapp/com.apps.epicad.andrewapp.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
08-18 19:08:21.515: ERROR/InputDispatcher(1310): channel '4070fd50 com.apps.epicad.andrewapp/com.apps.epicad.andrewapp.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-18 19:08:21.515: INFO/WindowManager(1310): WINDOW DIED Window{4070fd50 com.apps.epicad.andrewapp/com.apps.epicad.andrewapp.MainActivity paused=false}
08-18 19:08:21.515: ERROR/ActivityManager(1310): fail to set top app changed!
08-18 19:08:21.525: INFO/WindowManager(1310): WIN DEATH: Window{4070fd50 com.apps.epicad.andrewapp/com.apps.epicad.andrewapp.MainActivity paused=false}
08-18 19:08:21.545: DEBUG/Sensors(1310): Enable akm: en = 0
08-18 19:08:21.545: DEBUG/SensorService(1310): noteStopSensor: uid = 0x3e8, handle = 0x0
08-18 19:08:21.565: INFO/CarouselTimeLog(2737): onStart() finish: 1313719701567
08-18 19:08:21.565: DEBUG/CarouselDummyActivity(2737): CarouselDummyActivity.onResume: tab_allapps
08-18 19:08:21.565: DEBUG/Background traffic light(2737): traffic light: RED, mBackgroundTrafficLight = true
08-18 19:08:21.575: DEBUG/William(2737): - refreshUsageStatCache -
08-18 19:08:21.585: DEBUG/EASAppSvc(836): [ NA ]INTENT_PAUSE_SYNC:com.htc.launcher
08-18 19:08:21.605: DEBUG/InputManagerService(1310): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2548 uid 10161
08-18 19:08:21.605: WARN/InputManagerService(1310): [startInputLocked] Enable input method client.
08-18 19:08:21.625: DEBUG/AutoSetting(25998): service - mBroadcastReceiver: action = com.htc.content.Intent.ACTION_BACKGROUND_OP_STOP
08-18 19:08:21.625: DEBUG/EASAppSvc(836): [ NA ]setPause(com.htc.launcher)
08-18 19:08:21.645: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(1310): layer=0x691b08 is not in the purgatory list
08-18 19:08:21.645: DEBUG/EASAppSvc(836): [ NA ]MainHandlerThread: msg:{ what=33 when=-1d22h30m6s909ms }
08-18 19:08:21.655: DEBUG/EASRequestController(836): [Acc -1][syncSrcs=null]checkQueue(): paused
08-18 19:08:21.655: DEBUG/EASEventBroadcaster(836): [ NA ]resendSyncEvent(): exSyncSources is null, skip
08-18 19:08:21.735: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(1310): layer=0x65b980 is not in the purgatory list
08-18 19:08:21.745: DEBUG/AK8975(1223): Compass CLOSE 
08-18 19:08:22.215: DEBUG/ConnectivityService(1310): getMobileDataEnabled returning true
08-18 19:08:23.196: DEBUG/DEBUG(2737): updateCellLayoutCache(3.5555556, 3.5607476)
08-18 19:08:23.216: DEBUG/DEBUG(2737): updateCellLayoutCache(3.5555556, 3.5607476)
08-18 19:08:23.397: DEBUG/DEBUG(2737): updateCellLayoutCache(3.5555556, 3.5607476)
```

So it looks like it logcat says that there is no Activity to handle the intent, but I am pretty sure that there is.

Comment: Always use try catch around startActivity (launching a new activity). It is a good practice, also you ll come to know why the launch got failed and you ll not face ANR.

Comment: I don't think that is a good practice to use try catch around startActivity. It will clutter your code and if you catched an Exception how are  you supposed to handle it? If an activity can't start your app has to crash and you have to fix it. Try catch won't give you more then the stacktrace that is in logcat anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm... With quick glance, there are several problems. Your child activity name is UselessActivity, not Useless. And the activity is also tied to main.

Anyway, could you try this line instead when you call the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UselessActivity.class);
```

And then you can go from there.

Comment: The reason I called it UselessActivity was because it was supposed to do something useless. Nothing professional.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if your useless activity has any kind of error by making it the ***LAUNCHER*** activity in manifest file . If it loads properly , try invoking intent as below

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, UselessActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```